# addListenerForSingleValueEvent does not execute

Tags: java, firebase

I'm trying to Read data from Firebase via Java. The `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`, and anything I put inside it, does not execute. After searching through other related stack questions, I've been unable to find a non-Android related answer. Please take a look and let me know why this method is not executing. Thanks in advance.

```
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import java.io.*;

public class App {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        class ServiceFile {

            private FileInputStream mMyFile;

            public ServiceFile(String myFile) {
                try {
                    mMyFile = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                    System.out.println("The Service File exists. "); // this line prints
                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    System.out.println("The Service File does not exist.");
                }
            }

            public FileInputStream getMyFile() {
                return mMyFile;
            }
        }

        ServiceFile serviceFile = new ServiceFile("/Users/xxxx/Documents/development/javaFire/serviceAccountKey.json");

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setServiceAccount(serviceFile.getMyFile())
                .setDatabaseUrl("https://xxxx.firebaseio.com")
                .build();

        // Initialize the app
        FirebaseApp myApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

        // Get the reference to some location within the DB
        final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(myApp);
        DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("/users/john");

        // Attach a listener to read the data at the DB reference
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot theData) {
                System.out.println("Success! "); // this line does not print
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.out.println("Cancelled" + databaseError.getMessage()); // this line does not print
            }
        });

    }

}
```

My database rules are as such:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

My data in Firebase, at /users.json

```
{
  "john": {
    "dob": "02/20/1980" 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your callback is not executing because your program ends before the callback can receive new data.  Remember that `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` is asynchronous (it returns immediately), so your main function will return immediately, which means the JVM will exit.

At a very minimum, you could put a call to Thread.sleep() at the end of the function to make sure it doesn't terminate immediately.  But for a real program, you'll likely be doing something else.

Comment: Thanks Doug, adding a 1 second wait did allow the program to receive data prior to exiting - and printed the "Success!" message. Do you have any strategies/recommendations/resources that address other solutions?

Comment: Async operations in Firebase return a Task object.  You could learn how to use those.  I have a whole blog series on them starting here: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/09/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-1.html

Comment: I am facing a similar problem in an Android program. Is it possible for the same reason?